I reduced boot time just by removing `/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan`. Why it's so slow?
I use ubuntu 24.04 on a laptop.
Previously I had these problems:

very long boot times. systemd-analyze blame was telling me it was NetworkManager that take minutes to be booted

systemctl daemon-reload command was very slow. I have enabled the debug log-level and then I saw /lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan taking about one minutes to be reloaded.


After these investigations, I removed the /lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan and surprisingly, all of my previews problems has been solved.
But my question is, What was the actual problem? I want to dig deeper

Can you show the netplan yaml from the affected system? (/etc/netplan)

@slangasek It contains 26 yaml files. all of them are wifi username/passwords that i ever used

so ls -1 /etc/netplan | grep -v 90-NM shows no results?  If so please file a bug with ubuntu-bug netplan.io about this issue.

It seems like Ubuntu knows this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/2069495
The solution was pretty simple: remove the /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/netplan symlink.
Keep in your mind, you might have to eventually run netplan generate time to time, because this is what this symlink does on every package install.
